# Elasticsearch filter plugin from logstash rejects negative numbers

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm trying to use the [logstash elasticsearch filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html) to add tags to a data stream by joining two elasticsearch indexes with a common "identifier" field. The filter fails to execute when the identifier is a negative number.

The filter looks like:

```
filter {
   if [type] == "mysql-telemetry" {
      elasticsearch {
         hosts => ["localhost"]
         index => "mysql-properties"
         query => "identifier:%{identifier}"
         fields => [["datumname","datumname"],
                    ["datuminstance","datuminstance"],
                    ["originator","originator"],
                    ["originatorinstance","originatorinstance"],              
                    ["observatory","observatory"],
                    ["site","site"],
                    ["units","units"]
                   ]
         enable_sort => "false" 
      }
   }
}
```

The error seems to be complaining about the "-" sign from the identifier.

> RemoteTransportException[[Fatale][172.17.0.3:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"size":1,"query":{"query_string":{"query":"type:mysql-properties AND identifier:-4243310759994300850", "lowercase_expanded_terms":true, "analyze_wildcard":false}}, "sort":[{"datumname":{"order":"asc"}}]}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[Failed to parse query [type:mysql-properties AND identifier:-4243310759994300850]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse 'type:mysql-properties AND identifier:-4243310759994300850': Encountered " "-" "- "" at line 1, column 37.

I've tried adding escaped double quotes around %{identifier} but then get a different error

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""-4937399000822192745""

Should I be using different escaping, different quotes, different query?

Comment: How is the `identifier` field mapped? It looks like it's probably trying to parse that `long` as an `integer`, which would happen if the field is mapped improperly.

Comment: Thinking along the same lines I had already explicitly cast the `identifier` as a string in the mysql query but the `-` was still problematic. I managed to work around this issue by replacing the `-` with an `M` using mysql `replace()`.

Comment: Interesting. This seems likely to be fixable by correcting the mapping (schema) of the index. To be clear, it's a problem for ES rather than Logstash. If you copy/pasted that query to ES, then it would fail over there: `{"query":"type:mysql-properties AND identifier:-4243310759994300850", "lowercase_expanded_terms":true, "analyze_wildcard":false}}, "sort":[{"datumname":{"order":"asc"}}]}`

Comment: The query `identifier:-4243310759994300850` does fail in ES but `identifier:"-4243310759994300850"` succeeds. My problem was trying to introduce the double quotes through the filter.

Comment: query => "identifier:%{[identifier]}" this might work